# Can I enter the UK as a UK citizen and resident on an Australian passport?

Tags: visas, passports, uk-citizens

I'm about to travel to Europe and have misplaced my UK passport. I have an Australian passport which allows me entry to the the European countries in question without a visa.

However, what is the situation with me re-entering the UK on my Australian passport? Given the Australian passport will only let me stay for 90 days if I was not a UK citizen, is this likely to cause a problem when I come to leave or enter again in the future?

I have a UK birth certificate and could probably bring other forms of ID/proof of address if that helps.

Thanks,
Andy.

Comment: Do you live in the UK?

Comment: It's exactly the same situation as here http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/55860/uk-citizen-entering-the-uk-on-a-one-way-ticket-and-us-passport  Aussie/US passports are identical where the UK is concerned.